# How to add image overlay to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary when editing?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I've tried looking everywhere for an answer to this but can not find any useful info.

Basically, I want the user to pick a picture from the album, and then have the app display the picture in the edit/crop mode.

On this edit screen I want to display an overlay screen for the user to use to align his image.

He then clicks the save button which saves the edited picture with the overlay image by just merging the images.

**The only thing I can not find how to do is add the overlay image in the edit screen!**

I can do this quite easily when:

`imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`

But when:

`imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;`

I can not use:

`imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayGraphicView;`

and that is my issue.

Also if I add an UIimage as a subview instead then this overlay, it stays on the screen even when the user is choosing his image from the album. I only want the overlay to appear after the image has been chosen for editing and before it has been saved to the album after the editing has finished.

Thanks for your help.

Heres the method:

```
- (IBAction)pickPhotoButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pick a Current Photo Button Pressed...");

    // Create image picker controller
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    // Set source to the camera
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // Delegate is self
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    // Allow editing of image ?
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    // Show image picker
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
}
```

and heres my save to album method:

```
// Save the image to photo album
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

    // Combine image with overlay before saving!!
    image = [self addOverlayToImage:image];

    // Save image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can become `UIImagePickerController` object's delegate and keenly observe the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods - [`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007662-CH3-SW1) and `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. You can know when the second view controller is coming on and later add your overlay to the view controller's view. Sample usage is shown below –

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ( [navigationController.viewControllers count] == 2 ) {
        overlayView.center = CGPointMake(135, 135);
        overlayView.bounds = CGRectZero;

        [viewController.view addSubview:overlayView];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake( 50, 50, 220, 220)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks alot Deepak, that worked perfectly! Would have never been able to find that out myself, so the help was most definitely greatly appreciated! Would you by any chance also know how to take the edited image (cropped) of the full screen rather then the image just in the crop box? I dont want to take a screenshot as that would also show the bars etc...

Comment: I didn't get you on this one.

Comment: Basically, when you have chosen a image from the library it goes to the edit screen, on this screen is a square crop box in the center, i can edit the image here (pan and zoom) and then save the image to the library by clicking next. What i want to know is that how i can save the whole zoomed image and not just the one in the crop box? thanks

Comment: Take a look at [`UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage). Is it not what you're looking for?

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage saves the whole image as it was before editing (zooming & Panning) i need the image after the user has pinched to zoom, hence i think it would still be UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage. Basically i think i need a way to change the cropping rectangles width/height!!

Comment: Deepak, this works great for loading a photo from library, but it doesn't work for camera. Do you have a solution for camera?

Comment: In my app, the UIImagePickerController delegate is my UINavigationController already in use, and I can't be certain of anyone's position on the VC stack in the future.  Instead of the `if ( [navigationController.viewControllers count] == 2 )` test, I use `if ([[[[navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] class] description] isEqualToString:@"PLUIImageViewController"])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following customised method for adding overlays to the Imagepickercontroller

In yourclassname `.h` file define

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController*      m_Pickercontroller;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView;


 In yourclassname.m file

-(void)Loadcaptureview
{
   //Allocating Image Picker Controller 
    m_Pickercontroller=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init ];
    m_Pickercontroller.delegate=self;
    m_Pickercontroller.allowsEditing=YES;
    m_Pickercontroller.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    m_Pickercontroller.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300); 

    UIButton*Clickbutton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,200, 60, 60)];
    [Clickbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-circle-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Clickbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    image1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,400, 60, 60)];
    image1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-circle-button.png"];

    [m_Pickercontroller.cameraOverlayView addSubview:Clickbutton];
    [m_Pickercontroller.cameraOverlayView addSubview:image1];
    [m_Pickercontroller.cameraOverlayView bringSubviewToFront:image1];

    //Hiding the Camera Control
    m_Pickercontroller.showsCameraControls=NO;

    //Presenting the imagepicker Controller to Present Modal view Controller
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:m_Pickercontroller animated:YES];
    }

  // Calling the Function

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

   [self Loadcaptureview];

   }
```